# Tab session in Chrome plugin development

Tags: session, google-chrome-extension, tabs

Can we allow our plugin to run for every tab.

Right now my chrome extension is maintaining window session means If i open my chrome extension into two window then both are behaving as different different entity

But In 2 tabs of one window if i am opening my same plugin then it is behaving as 1 unit.

so please help me if we have any thing through which we can maintain session per tab.

In my content script i am writing my code like this -

```
$(document).ready(function() { 
if(window.location.href == "https://google.com/"){
     //Here i am writing my logic.
}
});
```

> mainifest.json

code

```
  "content_security_policy": "script-src 'self' http://localhost:8080; object-src 'self'",


    "content_scripts": [ {
    "js": [ "jquery_min.js", "credit_card.js" ],
     "matches": ["http://*/*", "https://*/*"]
  }],

    "web_accessible_resources": [
    "credit_card_info.html",
    "credit_card.css"
  ],


"permissions": [
  "tabs",
  "bookmarks",
  "http://www.blogger.com/",
  "http://*.google.com/",
  "unlimitedStorage",
  "http://localhost:8080/*"
  ]
}
```

Comment: content script should be tab session. You mean you also want the background to run as a tab session?

Comment: I have updated the my mainifest.json file. Kindly check if i can do any thing in it to maintain session.

Comment: can you post your "Permissions" of manifest file